# Enabling Sampling of covergroup SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, code-coverage, system-verilog

I am trying to run a functional coverage on my code, but I am getting a warning stating - `Sampling of covergroup type "LED_PANEL::CVG" (./design.sv:24), referred in the statement is not enabled. As a result, coverage methods get_coverage(), get_inst_coverage(), get_hitcount(), and get_inst_hitcount() will return 0 coverage. 0.000000 %`

I am not getting coverage printed in the log either. How do I enable coverage

Here is the coverage group I have created -

```
  covergroup CVG;
    LED11: coverpoint PANEL[0][1];
    LED12: coverpoint PANEL[0][2];
    LED13: coverpoint PANEL[0][3];
    LED14: coverpoint PANEL[0][0];
    LED21: coverpoint PANEL[1][1];
    LED22: coverpoint PANEL[1][2];
    LED23: coverpoint PANEL[1][3];
    LED24: coverpoint PANEL[1][0];
  endgroup: CVG
```

Here's the link to the code -
https://edaplayground.com/x/KUv3

Answer (score 1):

You have run into a tool setup issue on EDAPlayground. Choosing any other tool works.

Answer (score 1):

The Cadence simulator requires you to enable functional coverage when you run the simulation.  I added the required settings, and the coverage results are shown:

[EDA Playground](https://edaplayground.com/x/AkFN)

```
  Coverage: 100.000000 %
```

I added `-coverage all` to the "Compile options"